# Is Google Translate Phrasebook sync available for iOS

Tags: google-sync

Is Google Translate Phrasebook app sync available on iOS

Comment: I think the author of a question means, how to sync phrasebook on app with chrome browser on a mac or pc?

Answer (score 2):

As of today <s>(Sep 7th 2015)</s> July 23 2017 , it is still unavailable on the iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually No. This does not answer the question. The issue here is - can you save a translation in the Google Translate App to a phrasebook (on, say, an iPhone) and then pick up the same translation on an iPad (without having to enter and retranslate the expression).

My experience is that you cannot. Each device keeps it’s own individual phrasebook (and ‘never the twain shall meet’).

The only way (that I can think of) to do this is to have a user login for the app. Then whenever you log onto Google Translate, your saved translations (from your Phrasebook) become available as they are associated with you user id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[App Store - Google Translate](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/google-translate/id414706506?mt=8)

[Save translations in a phrasebook](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142480?hl=en)

> Add a phrasebook entry
>
> 1. Open the Translate app .
> 2. Translate the word or phrase you want to add.
> 3. Next to the translation, touch the star ☆.
>
> View or delete entries
>
> 1. Open the Translate app .
> 2. At the bottom of the page, touch the star ☆.
> 3. To delete a translation from your phrasebook, touch the star ☆.